# Несколько условий для sql скрипт

Tags: php, javascript, sql

Есть такой запрос

```
   if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] == 2 ) {
    if (!empty($_POST['number_points'])){
        $USP1= $_POST['st_performance'];
        $USP2= $_POST['semestr_performance'];
        $USP3= $_POST['academicYear_performance'];
        $USP4= $_POST['subject_performance'];
        $USP5= $_POST['vidKont_performance'];
        $USP6= $_POST['national'];
        $USP6ECTS= $_POST['ECTS'];
        $USP6_100= $_POST['number_points'];
        $USP7= $_POST['date_performance'];
        $USP8= $_POST['lecturer_performance'];
        $USP9= $_POST['type_statement'];
        $USP10= $_POST['statement_performance'];
        for ($i=0; $i < count($USP1) ; $i++) {
             $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO usp (USP1, USP2, USP3, USP4, USP5,USP6_100,USP6,USP6ECTS, USP7, USP8,USP9,USP10)
             VALUES ('$USP1[$i]', '$USP2', '$USP3', '$USP4', '$USP5', '$USP6_100[$i]','$USP6[$i]','$USP6ECTS[$i]', '$USP7[$i]', '$USP8', '$USP9[$i]', '$USP10[$i]')");
        }

        echo("Успешно добавлено");         
    }
    else {
        $USP1= $_POST['st_performance'];

    $USP2= $_POST['semestr_performance'];
    $USP3= $_POST['academicYear_performance'];
    $USP4= $_POST['subject_performance'];
    $USP5= $_POST['vidKont_performance'];
    $USP6= $_POST['national'];
    $USP6ECTS= $_POST['ECTS'];
    $USP6_100= $_POST['number_points'];
    $USP7= $_POST['date_performance'];
    $USP8= $_POST['lecturer_performance'];
    $USP9= $_POST['type_statement'];
    $USP10= $_POST['statement_performance'];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($USP1) ; $i++) {
         $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO usp (USP1, USP2, USP3, USP4, USP5,USP6_100,USP6,USP6ECTS, USP7, USP8,USP9,USP10)
         VALUES ('$USP1[$i]', '$USP2', '$USP3', '$USP4', '$USP5', NULL,NULL,NULL, NULL, '$USP8', NULL, NULL)");
        }

    echo("Успешно добавлено");
    }
    $mysqli->close() ;
}
```

Он работает, но частично, вот эта часть работает

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] == 2 ){
    if (!empty($_POST['number_points'])){
        $USP1= $_POST['st_performance'];
        $USP2= $_POST['semestr_performance'];
        $USP3= $_POST['academicYear_performance'];
        $USP4= $_POST['subject_performance'];
        $USP5= $_POST['vidKont_performance'];
        $USP6= $_POST['national'];
        $USP6ECTS= $_POST['ECTS'];
        $USP6_100= $_POST['number_points'];
        $USP7= $_POST['date_performance'];
        $USP8= $_POST['lecturer_performance'];
        $USP9= $_POST['type_statement'];
        $USP10= $_POST['statement_performance'];
        for ($i=0; $i < count($USP1) ; $i++) {
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO usp (USP1, USP2, USP3, USP4, USP5,USP6_100,USP6,USP6ECTS, USP7, USP8,USP9,USP10)
            VALUES ('$USP1[$i]', '$USP2', '$USP3', '$USP4', '$USP5', '$USP6_100[$i]','$USP6[$i]','$USP6ECTS[$i]', '$USP7[$i]', '$USP8', '$USP9[$i]', '$USP10[$i]')");
        }

        echo("Успешно добавлено");

    }
```

ТО есть, если там пустота, $_POST['number_points']) является пустой, то оно не сохраняет NULL в БД. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема может быть в том, что на это поле в таблице стоит ограничение 'NOT NULL'. Для того что бы получить ответ на впорос  добавьте к вопросу текст ошибки

Comment: Так нету ошибки никакой.Просто изначально, те поля они заполнены, но мне надо сделать так, что если $_POST['number_points']=пустота, то остальные(которые в запросе я поставил NULL), то сохранялись в БД с NULL. А запрос так не делает, он сохраняет со значениями, даже ,если $_POST['number_points'])= NULL

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде несколько ошибок:

- блок else не заключен в `{}`, поэтому если `!empty($_POST['number_points']) == true` то будут созданы дубли записи (с null и без)
- Не добавляется, поскольку ошибка в запросе. Перед последним `NULL` стоит апостроф

--

```
NULL, NULL, NULL, '$USP8', NULL, 'NULL)");
                                 ^вот тут
```

Comment: исправил (выше код), но почему все равно не работает